# separar con .split() titulo 'importe_divisa' de un dataframe con pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

al separar 'importe_divisa' para que me de por ejemplo 500  USD no me queda separado importe y divisa cambian de nombre a 0 y 1 como podria mantener los nombres? esto es lo que tengo.

```
importes = pd.DataFrame({'importe_divisa': ['592,50 EUR', '690,10 USD', '2951 GPD']})
importes
importes['importe_divisa'].str.split(expand=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pandas` no puede matenter los nombres de tu columna, porque ahora, has creado dos columnas, mientras que antes tenías una. ¿Cómo `Pandas` va a asignar el nombre?

Lo que puedes hacer es usar el método `split()` con las columnas también para procesarlas a tu gusto, tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
import pandas as pd
importes = pd.DataFrame({'importe_divisa': ['592,50 EUR', '690,10 USD', '2951 GPD']})

#Accedemos a la única columna que tenemos
importes_columnas = importes.columns[0]

importes = importes['importe_divisa'].str.split(expand=True)

#spliteamos la columna por la barra baja.
importes.columns = importes_columnas.split("_")
```

### Explicación

- `importes_columnas = importes.columns[0]`: con el atributo `columns` accedemos a las columnas de nuestro `DataFrame`, como solo tenemos una, y este atributo nos devuelve un objeto `index` **que es iterable** accedemos a la posición cero para quedarnos con un **dato tipo string** y lo guardamos en `importes_columnas`
- Despues de realizar tu operación, hacemos `importes_columnas.split("_")`, como tenemos un string, le podemos aplicar el método `.split()` que habías aplicado tu antes, y le indicamos que el caracter para separar sera `_`

**Salida:**

```
    importe divisa
0   592,50  EUR
1   690,10  USD
2   2951    GPD
```

Como vemos quedan las dos columnas con sus nombres.